# Is the Rise of Skywalker the last story for these characters?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

I know that the Rise of Skywalker was always meant to bring the Skywalker story to an end but have Disney, JJ Abraham’s or anyone else confirmed that we will definitely not see Poe, Finn or Rey in any future Star Wars movie or show?

In an interview on the Graham Norton Show Daisy Ridley stated that this is it for her in the Starwars Universe and she has been told this is the last Starwars movie she will ever appear in. So I am looking for any confirmation of that from Press interviews etc.

Comment: Given that they damn near killed the franchise, I suspect that another film with these characters is never gonna happen

Comment: I've voted to close as a subset of our "Future Works" policy. There's certainly no plans in the offing, but that could change tomorrow; https://www.flickeringmyth.com/2019/04/john-boyega-expects-star-wars-the-rise-of-skywalker-to-be-last-outing-as-finn/

Comment: I am looking for specific quotes from the cast or director. I know for instance that in an interview Daisy Ridley said that she knows she will never be returning as Rey in the future.

Comment: The problem with never is that never isn't always never in Hollywood

Comment: Richard, please recall that there was a time when Disney would never make a sequel to their animated features.

Comment: [The Rian Johnson trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars#Film) is presumably still happening, although I don't think any specifics whatsoever (including which characters might appear) have emerged about that.

Comment: We could only hope so :D

Comment: @RichardC: think Lucas made a similar statement to Ian MacDiarmid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At present there are no plans for a continuation of the main series which have been announced.  So far as the 'plan' for Star Wars is concerned, the main series is completed.

That said, the Star Wars universe is vast and has thousands of years of history, full of stories that can still be told.

According to [an article published recently](https://www.radiotimes.com/news/film/2019-12-07/star-wars-future-movies-films-tv-series-release-dates-the-mandalorian-rian-johnson-disney/) (early December, 2019) which claims it will update as further news is revealed, there are already several potential new series and movies upcoming.

The upcoming series include one that spins off of Rogue One featuring Cassian Andor and his droid, a series focused on Obi-Wan Kenobi, and the further release of episodes of The Mandalorian.

Disney also has scheduled at least three new films (releases schedule in December, two years apart) that mimic their release schedule of the most recent trilogy.  These movies do not currently have released titles, but there is speculation that they will be set in the Old Republic era and form a coherent story arc.

Lastly, it is important to remember that the plans a studio makes can, will, and do change.  There is literally no way to definitively say, "No, we will never see another movie featuring Poe, Finn, and Rey" because actors can return to a series when incentivized, roles can be recast, animated shows/movies are a thing, and if Disney sees a potential way to make money they are certain to take it.

**TL;DR:** Star Wars isn't going anywhere, and we can never be certain they won't put the new trilogy's characters in any upcoming works.

Comment: "there is speculation that they will ... form a coherent story arc".  Good luck with that!

Comment: @workerjoe - Like most speculation on the internet, it's likely baseless ;-)